# Default-Route for root of application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I tell my `mvc`-application to route to a specific `Controller` and `Action` when they are not specified?

When debugging `http://localhost:54500/` should route to `http://localhost:54500/Home/Index`.

Currently I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But this always throws

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

**Edit #1**

It should redirect/route to an View which resides in a `Area` called `Home`. Just want to clarify, that there is a `Controller` and an `Area` which both are named `Home`.

The config for the area is:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Home_default",
        "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

Comment: Do you have view called Index.cshtml under Views/Home folder in your project?

Comment: Calling `http://localhost:54500/Home/Home/Index` works fine.

Comment: That means your folder hierarchy is wrong. It should be `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When debugging http://localhost:54500/ should route to http://localhost:54500/Home/Index.

Actually, the way you have it configured, http://localhost:54500/ will route to the `HomeController.Index` method, not another URL.

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

This error indicates that routing succeeded, but the controller returned the path of a view that does not exist.

Since you also mentioned you are using an Area and have posted your configuration, it is clear what is happening. Your config is run in this order:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Home_default",
        "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

So, if you pass the URL `http://localhost:54500/`, the Area route will miss (because it doesn't start with `/Home`) and it will match the `Root` route. This `Root` route does not route to your Area. There are 2 ways to fix this.

### Option 1 - Add the Root Route to the Home Area

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Root",
        "",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Home_default",
        "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

### Option 2 - Set the DataToken to indicate the Home Area

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Home_default",
        "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    ).DataTokens["area"] = "Home";

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Maybe an issue with `Area`s?

Comment: Possibly, but unless you post your entire routing configuration (in order), it is not possible to tell which route matches first.

Comment: Where is your Area configuration for routing? You mentioned you are using Areas. Are you also using attribute routing? That is more routing config to take into consideration to solve this. The first match wins, not the best match. So to see what matches first, we need to see the entire config.

Comment: Please see my updated question. And, no, currently there is no `AttributeRouting` set

Comment: Going for `Option #2` as this fits more into my needs and feels like a good solution when adding more and more `Areas` later without thinking about the default(-root)-route. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Core 1.0.1 you can do this in Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
                 template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                   // template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
                   template: "{area=MyArea}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
```