# Visual Studio 2017 wont build project

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin

I'm having an issue with VS and can't seem to shake the problem. All my other teammates don't have the issue and no one can seem to find the reason why mine is being caused. When I run a build I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

After searching google it seems the problem is somehow Microsoft.Owin version is wrong comparatively to my .csproj file and packages.config file. When I reinstalled this package and double checked that all versions were correct (.csproj, packages.config, web.config), I built the project and this page launched.

[image]

As you can see the page above doesn't really have a whole lot of information so I really have no clue what to do next. I've recloned my repo like 10 times in various locations and with different names. I've completely uninstalled VS and reinstalled twice without any avail. I'm a frontend developer and this is my first project in ASP.net so I really don't know where to begin on this and my backend developer teammates seem equally perplexed. Has anyone had a similar issue, any ideas how to fix, or where I can get more information on what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Then you do need to learn what is ASP.NET. You are accessing `/` of a site, and if no routing is properly configured, of course no response other than 404 would be there. You might be new to ASP.NET, but your team mates might not. Find someone and learn from him/her, and that's much quicker than asking on SO.

Comment: Routing is properly configured. The project was working fine until I reclonned a few days ago. The issue is specific to my computer, I’ve spent the last two days debugging with the asp.net developers and am using stack overflow as a last resort. I’d be glad to provide additional information if it’s helpful but learning the entire Asp.net framework doesn’t seem helpful as an immediate solution.

Comment: "Routing is properly configured". Edit your question to include some evidence. `/` should not be routed by default, which requires some code change, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878491/default-route-for-root-of-application

Comment: Page clearly means that you are trying to load a resource which is not really available. Can you confirm it has the file you are trying to view?

Comment: Codelt after further debugging and setting a break point on the router we’ve realized the routing module isn’t even being hit.

Comment: Maybe this is an IIS issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config try adding:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This falls under the **configuration > runtime > assemblyBinding** section

Comment: Hey Chad, thanks for the advice. I actually already have this in my web.config file as well. Is there anything else I can provide to help with debugging?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is the nuget package is lingering. Try going into the file system ProjectDir\Project\packages\ and clear that out. Also check your packages.config file in your project to ensure the Microsoft.Owin package is not misconfigured.

Comment: Actually, if you have an old version of Microsoft.Owin in your GAC for some reason that may cause this issue as well.

Comment: I have to step away for a hour but I’ll check when I get back in. Is it possible that I could have some packages cached globally on my hardddive?

Comment: Sorry I re-read the question and I believe your project is building now without the Owin error, if so, this may be unrelated at this point. To help further I need to know what the architecture of your app is and what is supposed to be showing on that page. Is it MVC, is that a view of some sort, does the controller get hit, etc etc.

Comment: I’ll get one of the backend developers on here to give you this info while I’m out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: We set a break point on the router and it’s not being hit. I’m trying to get a bit more information to further explain my problem. We are using an MVC but because the router isn’t hitting I imagine neither the controller or view is hitting.

Comment: I’m starting to think this is an issue with IIS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174521/discussion-between-chad-h-and-jleibham).